# Magento 2.3 disable or secure API access

Tags: api, magento2.3

In the developer docs I've found the option to unrestrict API access. Is there an option to restrict access to the API for everything i.e. nothing is anonymous? Or is there a way to disable the magento API?

Maybe I misunderstand but seems like bots can spam your API endpoint to retrieve a lot of information.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/anonymous-api-security.html

*Update*

Am I correct in saying that Magento 1 doesn't allow anonymous access?

Comment: If you disable Magento 2 API, your checkout won't work anymore.

Comment: Do you think this is a good idea? Surely it would have been a good idea to automatically generate a checkout api user on install and use this user on the checkout?

Comment: If you want to protect the then i suggest to use Web firewall. The application cannot stop hitting   at URL & rest points.If you have too bot traffic at the network level.So suggest using Web-firewall

Comment: there is only God and one crazy magento developer know why API works this way...

Comment: @AmitBera Sounds good.  Am I right in saying Magento 1 doesn't allow anonymous access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using nginx correct way would be to map all API endpoints and configure some access logic.

```
map $request_uri $api_access {
        default 0;
        ~/(.*)/V1/carts/mine                        0; # example to pass?
        ~/(.*)/async/bulk/V1/customers              1;
        ~/(.*)/V1/customers(?!/me)                  1;
        ~/(.*)/V1/customers/password                1;
        ~/(.*)/V1/customers/resetPassword           1;
        ~/(.*)/V1/customers/isEmailAvailable        1;
        ~/(.*)/V1/guest-carts/                      1;
        ~/(.*)/V1/integration/                      1;
        ~/(.*)/V1/products-render-info              1;
        ~/(.*)/V1/search                            1;
        ......
        ......
        map every endpoint you like!
}

if ($api_access) { 

    some logic to log / verify / limit access;
    set $foo bar;
    rewrite @to_magento;

}
```

disable guest checkout is also good option, today in online business is better to know your customers are legit.

Comment: have you restricted API access in anyway?

Comment: you can block it completely and only allow access for specific use. like ERP etc...

Comment: i believe that API must be separate from application itself, running remotely only, running it within the application is stupid.

Comment: I have *exactly* the same feeling. Although I felt stupid making a fuss about it. But it just didn't sit me right either.